# Alamofire JSON serialization error - Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm having issues posting JSON via Alamofire.  I'm getting the error below.  My parameters are as noted - any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
    let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
        "t": [
            "name": "foo",
            "event": "tap",
            "ts":  NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
        ],
        "z": [["key": "12345"], ["key": "67890"]]
    ]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://myapi.com/test", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
```

Error Domain=com.alamofire.error Code=-6006 "JSON could not be serialized. Input data was nil or zero length." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=JSON could not be serialized. Input data was nil or zero length.}

Comment: Your dictionary can be easily converted in `NSData` using `NSJSONSerialization` object. Are you sure you aren't receiving this error while serializing the response JSON?

Answer (score 0):

`NSDate` is not a valid JSON object. You need to convert it to a String (most likely) using one of many RFC or ISO specs using an NSDateFormatter. Here's an example of an `ISO8601` date.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"

let iso8601String = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
```

Using this logic, you will first need to convert your `NSDate` parameter into a `String`, then add the `String` version to your parameters dictionary and Alamofire will handle it from there.